# how to remove a particular subview from superview which has multiple subviews in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm adding multiple views into a view using loop.

```
float contactsContainerX = 6.0f;

UIView *contactsContainer=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,4.0f,110.0f,22.0f)];
            contactsContainer.backgroundColor=[UIColor  colorWithRed:213.0f/255.0f green:213.0f/255.0f blue:213.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

UIButton *closeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90.0f, 2.0f, 18.0f, 18.0f)];
closeButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

[closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(removeFavouriteContact:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[contactsContainer addSubview:closeButton];

for(int x=0; x<3;x++)
{
   contactsContainer.frame = CGRectMake(contactsContainerX, contactsContainer.frame.origin.y, contactsContainer.frame.size.width, contactsContainer.frame.size.height);
   [self.contactsViewSuperContainers addSubview:contactsContainer];
    contactsContainerX = contactsContainer.frame.origin.x + contactsContainer.frame.size.width+6.0f;
    self.contactsScroller.contentSize =CGSizeMake(contactsContainerX,self.contactsViewSuperContainers.frame.size.height);
}
```

Now whenever I click on the button. The action should remove the particular subview which I clicked.I mean what is the code? Please help me.

```
-(void) removeFavouriteContact: (UIButton *) sender
{

    for(UIView *subview in self.contactsScroller.subviews)
        if (self.contactsScroller.subviews) 
        {
            //<#statements#>
            //[self.view removeFromSuperview];

        }

}
```

Comment: [[sender superview] removeFromSuperview];

Comment: Your first block of code doesn't seem right. Inside your loop you add the same view each time. A view can only be added to another view once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your `Button` is directly added to the `View` you are adding in loop, you can easily access the `SuperView` in you action by using

```
-(void) removeFavouriteContact :(id)sender {
    [[sender superview] removeFromSuperView];
}
```

The above code will only work if your button is directly added to the view, if not check the level of button where it is added, in deep level you can just append `superview` and get the exact superview like below

```
[[[[sender superview] superview] superview] removeFromSuperView];
```

Hope it helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

use `tag` and `viewWithTag` properties. Set `tag` for your `view` & `button` and get that `view` using `tag` then remove it.

```
-(void) removeFavouriteContact :(id)sender {
    NSInteger tag = sender.tag;
    UIView *view = [contactsContainer viewWithTag:tag];
    [view removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Comment: As I'm using the same UIView to generate multiple views if I set tag for each UIView, the last value of the loop is storing as final tag value. so whenever I click any of the subviews button the '2' is logged.

Comment: @rmaddy, already mentioned that you are doing it wrong. you should add your view only once.

Answer (score -1):

Use only one line

[[someUIView subviews]
   makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

Comment: This removes all subviews. The OP just wants to remove one subview.